# Extracting 5 years of twitter data using an API

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to scrape 7 years of data from 2012-01-01 to 2018-12-31. I am using tweepy and I have the following code

```
usernames = ["CNBC","MarketWatch","verge","YahooFinance"]
api = tweepy.API(auth)

start_date = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,0,0,0)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017,12,31,0,0,0)



def create_dictionary(username="",tweet_id="",time="",text="",retweet_count=0,favourite_count=0):
    
    return { 
        "USERNAME": username,
        "TWEET_ID": tweet_id,
        "TIME": time,
        "TWEET": text,
        "RETWEET_COUNT":retweet_count,
        "FAVOURITE_COUNT":favourite_count
    }   

tweet_id = []
time = []
tweet = []
rt_count = []
fav_count = []

for i,username in enumerate(usernames):
    print("Scraping for {}".format(username))
    for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=username).items():
        print(f'Last status had timestamp @ {status.created_at}')
        if status.created_at < start_date:
            break
        if (status.created_at >= start_date and status.created_at <= end_date) :
            tweet_id.append(str(status.id))
            time.append(str(status.created_at))
            tweet.append(status.text)
            rt_count.append(status.retweet_count)
            fav_count.append(status.favorite_count)
    dictionary = [
        create_dictionary(username=username,
                        tweet_id = val[0],time=val[1],text=val[2],retweet_count=val[3],favourite_count=val[4])
        for val in zip(tweet_id,time,tweet,rt_count,fav_count)
    ]
    clear_output(wait=True)
    try:
        print("Going for the next username {}".format(usernames[i+1]))
    except:
        print("Done")
        pass
    with open('training_tweets.json', 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(dictionary, fp,indent=4)
```

Nothing is being scraped and it moves to the next username, `[]` is being dumped in the json file.

Is there a rate-limit, are there other API to scrape historical twitter data?

Comment: Please add the error and the full stack trace to the question

Comment: There are no error, the scraper is failing to scrape and it moves to next username. Only [] is dumped in the json file

Comment: "But I am having a timeout error". So you do not have a timeout error then.

Comment: No I don’t have a timeout, it is just moving to the next username till it reaches the end.

Comment: If your code works fine using start and end dates within the last 12 months then it's a limitation of the API itself.

Comment: Probably it is rate limited based on number of requests that I can access. It didn’t stretch out for 12 months, got terminated before that. Also it is rate limited for each username. So after exceeding the limit it moved into next username

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are using here is hitting the Twitter user Timeline endpoint. This API only supports retrieving up to 3200 of the most recent Tweets from an individual user.

All of the accounts you have listed are high-volume media accounts with hundreds of thousands of Tweets posted to date, so the chances that you would see any Tweets from even 2017 in your result set are very small.

In order to retrieve Tweets from that time period, you would need to use [Twitter's full archive search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/search-api/overview), which is a premium API with a limited free tier. The volumes are likely to be high.

Comment: All right I will go through the documentation. Is the rate limit time-bounded? I mean 3200 tweets for 15 minutes? I am asking because then I can probably insert sleep for 15 minutes. Probably this will not work as it always starts searching from the present time. Better to go through the documentation, Thanks

Comment: The *maximum total number of Tweets available on a timeline* is 3200 Tweets, backwards from now.

You can make requests of up to 200 Tweets per request. You can make up to 900 requests per 15 minute window. There is an overall cap of 100,000 calls in a 24 hour period.

Using the timelines API is not the right solution for what you are trying to do here. You need to use full archive search.